# Having issue with UTL_mail.send for subject length more than 47

Tags: oracle

I am using **utl_mail.send** for automate email in my Pl-SQL package.
When i use the subject charater length more than 47 then the body of the email is getting corrupted(Attached the screenshot). Shorter subject length e-mail is coming perfect.

```
declare 
begin
        utl_mail.send(sender => 'Test@supersoft.com',
                      subject => 'test10 Test10 more than 47 test 1234567890912312453254325345',
                      message => 'Test',
                      mime_type => 'text/plain; charset=us-ascii',
                      recipients => 'interanet@supersoft.com');
end;
```

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Could anyone please help me what might be the issue with this.

Comment: does the provided answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have read this article, [Does UTL_MAIL have an attachment limit of 32k](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:494228200346768899), on [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com) earlier today, and this seems to be a bug. As he advised, you should check for patch support in [MOSC](http://metalink.oracle.com):

The question:

```
I am on 10g release 2 on windows 64 bit. 
When I tried to send an email with subject more than 44( or so ) characters . it gets truncated. 
Is there any limitation in using this package ?
I could not see any limitations specified in the documentation or in metalink.
```

His Anonymous Block:

```
begin 
    utl_mail.send ( sender      => 'sender@ru.com" , 
                    recipients  => "powerusers@ru.com" , 
                    subject     => "Process is completed for both Sales Order Data."
                    test        => "Test");
end;
```

The asker's output (similar to yours):

```
Subject: Process is completed for both Sales Order D

=?WINDOWS-1252?Q?ata.?=
X-Priority: 3
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="------------4D8C24=_23F7E4A13B2357B3"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------4D8C24=_23F7E4A13B2357B3
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Test
```

Tom's Answer:

```
I see some filed issues regarding this with support. 
Your options would be 
a) file an issue with support and see if a patch exists for your system. 
b) use utl_smtp to send the mail yourself.
```